# amcharts chart insertion in Leaflet control

Tags: javascript, leaflet, amcharts

I'm coding a website in which i insert a chart in the map canvas, exactly as a legend would be inserted:

<>The graph plotter (cf http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/your-first-chart-with-amcharts/)

```
function grapher(chartData) {  
    var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    [...]
    chart.addGraph(graph);
    chart.write('chartdiv');
    return chart;
};
```

<>The leaflet control (cf http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html)

```
var courbe = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'}); 
courbe.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div       = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
    div.id        = "chartdiv"
    div.style     = "width: 400px; height: 200px;"
    return div;
};
```

<>

```
courbe.addTo(map);
grapher(json);
```

On firefox, everything works fine. And checking the canvas element on firebug shows what desired, that is :

```
class="width: 400px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden; text-align: left;"
```

On chrome, the 400px by 200px frame is collapsed, as an empty leaflet control, and analogously :

```
class="overflow: hidden; text-align: left;"
```

Has my problem something to deal with this question : [amCharts doesn't display chart for initially-hidden divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013408/amcharts-doesnt-display-chart-for-initially-hidden-divs))

Safari behaves as Chrome. Actually, it only displays correctly with firefox. Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I simply put the width and height parameters in my customized info css style, as follows :

```
.info {
    padding: 6px 8px;
    font: 12px/14px courier;
    background: white;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
 +  width: 400px;
 +  height: 200px;
}
```