# Amcharts toggle not displaying

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using this amchart..

When I am applying toggle for two chart it is displaying nothing there.. I think there is something invalid size method will be used for this if yes where to where to use invalid size method?

One more thing I want to achieve something like when clicking on each bar of chart1 seperate values will placed in chart2 and chart 3.

.

This is something I found on stackoverflow but not sure it is good solution or not.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013408/amcharts-doesnt-display-chart-for-initially-hidden-divs?lq=1
```

My JSFiddle    http://jsfiddle.net/umairorana/b72fvqyt/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the DOM element that a chart is being rendered too must be visible for the render to work correctly. Therefore you must toggle the display, and render chart2 and chart3 if the chart container is visible. I've include an updated JSFiddle with the working solution.

```
        chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", function() {
            $( "#panelchart" ).toggle();
            if($("#panelchart").is(":visible")) {
                RenderChart2();
                RenderChart3();
            }
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7coq6L7g/

Comment: Thanks for your reply i did that with this http://jsfiddle.net/b72fvqyt/14/ using validsize